# javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Undefined port type:

Tags: java, maven, soap, wsdl

I am trying to create a client for my WSDL service. When I try and consume/use the service I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Undefined port type:
```

I am generating my WSDL binding via JAXWS. The only port type which may be undefined is the `String[][]` input for the register function (originally I used ArrayLists however, they can't be parsed correctly by the JAXWS so I changed them to arrays).

```
<message name="register">
<part xmlns:ns1="http://jaxb.dev.java.net/array" name="endUserDetailsInput" type="ns1:stringArrayArray"/>
</message>
```

So when I try and use the register method in the CLI:

```
Controller controller = new Controller();
//Hardcoded Student/AcademicStaff here.
String[] rec1 = {"0","Student"};
String[] rec2 = {"1","Student"};
String[] rec3 = {"2","Student"};
String[] rec4 = {"3","Student"};
String[] rec5 = {"4","Student"};
String[] rec6 = {"5","AcademicStaff"};
String[] rec7 = {"6","AcademicStaff"};
String[][] endUserList = {rec1,rec2,rec3,rec4,rec5,rec6,rec7};
controller.batchReg(endUserList);
```

and in the controller:

```
public class Controller {
    public void batchReg(String[][] records){
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/EndUserService/?wsdl");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (url == null) {
            System.out.println("Failed");
        }
        QName qname = new QName("http://EndUserService/","EndUserServiceImplService");
        Service service = Service.create(url,qname);
        EndUserService obj = service.getPort(EndUserService.class);
        obj.register(records);
        System.out.println("Complete!");
    }
}
```

I get the error. If required I can provide the full WSDL file and other files but I think it must be that part because the other inputs and outputs in the system are all primitive types.

If I can't use ArrayLists or Arrays of Arrays, could you suggest an alternative data type that would work, or a work around? I could manually register each end user but that would be a task onto itself, and I wanted to avoid it if possible.

Any help appreciated.

**Full Error Print out**

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Undefined port type: {http://controller/}EndUserService
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:406)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:412)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:188)
    at controller.Controller.batchReg(Controller.java:28)
    at view.CLI.main(CLI.java:21)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be your webservice anotation doesn't has an endpointInterface.

You need to provide the port name

```
EndUserService obj = service.getPort(qname,EndUserService.class);
```

Or include an endpointInterface in you @WebService annotation
`@WebService(endpointInterface="com.something"...)`

Comment: I have added that now, reran and it produced this error: avax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: {http://EndUserService/}EndUserServiceImplService is not a valid port. Valid ports are: {http://EndUserService/}EndUserServiceImplPort